# MYSQL Code error, ODBC connector for stamps.com

Tags: mysql, import, odbc, stamps.com

I'm trying to update this script for use on the stamps.com servers.

The `ssx_customers.name` value comes from another table.

```
SELECT
contacts_cstm.num9c             as OrderId,
contacts_cstm.order_compleate_c     as OrderDate,
contacts_cstm.num9c             as RecipientFirstName,
contacts_cstm.ship_address_c    as RecipientLastName,
contacts_cstm.bisname_c         as RecipientCompany,
contacts_cstm.ship_address_city_c   as RecipientAddress1,
ssx_customers.name          as RecipientAddress2,


FROM contacts_cstm

LEFT OUTER JOIN ssx_customers
ON contacts_cstm.ssx_customers_id_c = ssx_customers.id


WHERE contacts_cstm.order_compleate_c BETWEEN #09/09/2018# AND #09/12/2018#
```

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Unrelated to your error, remove the comma from your last select column `ssx_customers.name as RecipientAddress2,`

Comment: Can you post the entire error you're getting?

Comment: That fixed it! thank you very much!!

Comment: No problem, I added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there should be no comma on the last select:

```
SELECT
contacts_cstm.num9c             as OrderId,
contacts_cstm.order_compleate_c     as OrderDate,
contacts_cstm.num9c             as RecipientFirstName,
contacts_cstm.ship_address_c    as RecipientLastName,
contacts_cstm.bisname_c         as RecipientCompany,
contacts_cstm.ship_address_city_c   as RecipientAddress1,
ssx_customers.name          as RecipientAddress2 -- ',' was here


FROM contacts_cstm

LEFT OUTER JOIN ssx_customers
ON contacts_cstm.ssx_customers_id_c = ssx_customers.id


WHERE contacts_cstm.order_compleate_c BETWEEN #09/09/2018# AND #09/12/2018#
```